# QRCODE LARAVEL is blurry

Tags: laravel, qr-code, blurry

I created a QRCODE size is 80 why logo inside QRcode and QRcode is blurry
how do I fix it?
I want to QRcode and img in the logo isn't blurry.

this is my code.

```
 QrCode::format('png')->merge(public_path('img/test.jpg'), 0.5, true)
        ->size(80) 
        ->errorCorrection('H') 
        ->backgroundColor(0, 0, 0) 
        ->color(231,195,111)
        ->generate('test'));
```

this is the solution.
[image]

Comment: QR codes aren't a default Laravel feature. If we need to have any chance to help you, we need to know which library you are using or see the code you use to generate the QR code.

Comment: i use simplesoftwareio/simple-qrcode